# pipe angular 2 filter component in category by enum

Tags: angular, pipe

Ihave a problem i would like to filter my list of component by her category but my pipe don't work can you help me

this is my pipe :

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'matchCategory'
})
export class MatchesCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<any>, category: string): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => item.category === category);
  }
}

<!-- list of category!-->


export enum ComponentCategory {
  FormControls = <any> 'Form Controls',
  Containers = <any> 'Containers' ,
  Boxes = <any> 'Boxes',
  DataPresentation = <any> 'Data Presentation',
  Layout = <any> 'Layout',
  Miscellaneous = <any> 'Miscellaneous',
  All = <any> 'All'
}
```

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let c of componentDescriptorsList | matchCategory: c.category" [ngValue]="'Form Controls'">
      <!--<tr *ngFor="let c of componentDescriptorsList">-->
        <td><a href="#/components/{{c.selector}}">{{c.title}}</a></td>
        <td>&#60;{{c.selector}}&#62;</td>
        <td>{{c.description}}</td>
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>
```

my list of component have a category and i would like to display for exemple just component who categoryis "form Controls"

thanks

Comment: have you registered the pipe in app.module.ts

Comment: no i don' t but now i have write in app.module and i have a new error

Comment: i post the error log in anwser

Comment: remove [ngValue]="'Form Controls'"

Comment: ok my serve is running now but i dont have my category th log is this RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/ComponentContainer.ngfactory.js:307:109)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]

Comment: if you trying to use pipes and all please check this link , it a repo by me hosted on gh-pages might help you or you can post your queries here 

link 


https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: where is your category ? can you have a plunker for the same , its very confused , there are plenty of other errors in your code i feel

Comment: i have post the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'matchesCategory'
})
export class MathcesCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Array<any>, category: string): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => item.category === category);
    }
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let model; of models | matchesCategory:model.category" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
<select (change)="selectedCategory = $event.target.value">
   <option *ngFor="let model of models ">{{model.category}}</option>
</select>
```

basic example for pipes using angular2

Answer (score 0):

```js
pipe category


import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'matchCategory'
})
export class MatchesCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<any>, category: string): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => item.category === category);
  }
}
```

```css
html file to display component & category

<tr *ngFor="let c of componentDescriptorsList | matchCategory: c.category" >
      <!--<tr *ngFor="let c of componentDescriptorsList">-->
        <td><a href="#/components/{{c.selector}}">{{c.title}}</a></td>
        <td>&#60;{{c.selector}}&#62;</td>
        <td>{{c.description}}</td>
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>
      </tr>
```

```html
typeScript file

import { TypeDecorator } from '@angular/core'
import {
  makeDecorator,
  makePropDecorator
} from './decorators'

export enum ComponentCategory {
  FormControls = <any> 'Form Controls',
  Containers = <any> 'Containers' ,
  Boxes = <any> 'Boxes',
  DataPresentation = <any> 'Data Presentation',
  Layout = <any> 'Layout',
  Miscellaneous = <any> 'Miscellaneous',
  All = <any> 'All'
}

export interface ComponentDescriptorDecorator {
  (obj: ComponentDescriptor): TypeDecorator
  new (obj: ComponentDescriptor): ComponentDescriptor
}

export interface Descriptor {
  title: string
  description: string
}

export interface ComponentDescriptor extends Descriptor {
  category: ComponentCategory
  creationDate: Date
  updatedDate?: Date
  relatedComponents?: any[]
  tags?: string[]
  deprecated?: boolean
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]